# Can not launch Steam games

Tags: dell, games, steam

I have found a few posts but there was no definite answer to any of them. I have lubuntu with a old dell XPS (specs will be below). My issue is that after spending 10 hours to get steam to actually launch ( I had to delete the old out of date libraries.) I now can not get games to launch from steam. The only game that launches from steam is Borderlands 2. All other games I have to install and then launch from the executable in the game file. I normally would have no problem with this but when you launch games this way, they can not connect to steam.

specs
Dell XPS 720 mobo
Radion 5850 GPU
Core 2 Duo 2.6GHz CPU
6 gigs of ram

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Why can't you launch steam games? What happens when you try to launch a steam game? Any errors? Please try to explain the problem in non-vague terms.

Answer (score 0):

You ought to completely remove the ~/.local/share/Steam folder, then run
sudo apt-get purge steam.
After that, reinstall steam.